# Seaborn jointplot: Regression with histogram but without kernel

Tags: python, seaborn

When using `seaborn`'s [joint plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) function, setting `kind=reg` will draw a scatter plot with regression line, an outer histogram and an estimated kernel density [(see here)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

I would like to get all of that, but not the kernel density estimation. However, it seems that the `kind` switch either gives me all or nothing. The only conceivable alternative is to use a standard `regplot` and then manually add the histograms around it.. is there any more convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seaborn [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) has arguments

> `{joint, marginal, annot}_kws` : dicts, optional
>   Additional keyword arguments for the plot components.

Since it plots a `distplot` to the marginal axes, the `marginal_kws` needs to be used to pass additional keyword arguments to `distplot`.

The argument to be used to turn the kde off is found in the [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) documentation

> `kde` : bool, optional
>   Whether to plot a gaussian kernel density estimate.